# Plot secondary x_axis in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

Dear All seniors and members,

Hope you are doing great. I have data set, which I like to plot the secondary x-axis in ggplot. I could not make it to work for the last 4 hours. below is my dataset.

```
                                Pathway    ES   NES p_value q_value  Group
1                            HALLMARK_HYPOXIA  0.49  2.25   0.000   0.000    Top
2  HALLMARK_EPITHELIAL_MESENCHYMAL_TRANSITION  0.44  2.00   0.000   0.000    Top
3                     HALLMARK_UV_RESPONSE_DN  0.45  1.98   0.000   0.000    Top
4                 HALLMARK_TGF_BETA_SIGNALING  0.48  1.77   0.003   0.004    Top
5                 HALLMARK_HEDGEHOG_SIGNALING  0.52  1.76   0.003   0.003    Top
6            HALLMARK_ESTROGEN_RESPONSE_EARLY  0.38  1.73   0.000   0.004    Top
7                  HALLMARK_KRAS_SIGNALING_DN  0.37  1.69   0.000   0.005    Top
8          HALLMARK_INTERFERON_ALPHA_RESPONSE  0.37  1.54   0.009   0.021    Top
9            HALLMARK_TNFA_SIGNALING_VIA_NFKB  0.32  1.45   0.005   0.048    Top
10                   HALLMARK_NOTCH_SIGNALING  0.42  1.42   0.070   0.059    Top
11                       HALLMARK_COAGULATION  0.32  1.39   0.031   0.067    Top
12                   HALLMARK_MITOTIC_SPINDLE  0.30  1.37   0.025   0.078    Top
13                      HALLMARK_ANGIOGENESIS  0.40  1.37   0.088   0.074    Top
14        HALLMARK_WNT_BETA_CATENIN_SIGNALING  0.35  1.23   0.173   0.216    Top
15         HALLMARK_OXIDATIVE_PHOSPHORYLATION -0.65 -3.43   0.000   0.000 Bottom
16                    HALLMARK_MYC_TARGETS_V1 -0.49 -2.56   0.000   0.000 Bottom
17                       HALLMARK_E2F_TARGETS -0.45 -2.37   0.000   0.000 Bottom
18                        HALLMARK_DNA_REPAIR -0.46 -2.33   0.000   0.000 Bottom
19                      HALLMARK_ADIPOGENESIS -0.42 -2.26   0.000   0.000 Bottom
20             HALLMARK_FATTY_ACID_METABOLISM -0.41 -2.06   0.000   0.000 Bottom
21                        HALLMARK_PEROXISOME -0.43 -2.01   0.000   0.000 Bottom
22                    HALLMARK_MYC_TARGETS_V2 -0.43 -1.84   0.003   0.001 Bottom
23           HALLMARK_CHOLESTEROL_HOMEOSTASIS -0.42 -1.83   0.003   0.001 Bottom
24               HALLMARK_ALLOGRAFT_REJECTION -0.34 -1.78   0.000   0.003 Bottom
25                  HALLMARK_MTORC1_SIGNALING -0.32 -1.67   0.000   0.004 Bottom
26                       HALLMARK_P53_PATHWAY -0.29 -1.52   0.000   0.015 Bottom
27                    HALLMARK_UV_RESPONSE_UP -0.28 -1.41   0.013   0.036 Bottom
28   HALLMARK_REACTIVE_OXYGEN_SPECIES_PATHWAY -0.35 -1.39   0.057   0.040 Bottom
29                   HALLMARK_HEME_METABOLISM -0.26 -1.34   0.014   0.061 Bottom
30                    HALLMARK_G2M_CHECKPOINT -0.23 -1.20   0.080   0.172 Bottom
```

I like to plot like the following plot (plot # 1)

**Here is my current codes chunks.**

```
ggplot(data, aes(reorder(Pathway, NES), NES, fill= Group)) + 
theme_classic() + geom_col()  + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, size = 8),
axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12), 
axis.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 8), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + labs(x="Pathway", y="Normalized Enrichment Score",
title="2Gy_5f vs. 0Gy") + coord_flip()
```

This code produces the following plot (plot # 2)

So I would like to generate the plot where I have secondary x-axis with q_value (same like the first bar plot I have attached). Any help is greatly appreciated. Note: I used coord_flip so it turn angle of x-axis.

Kind Regards,

synat
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBFIS.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDbC5.jpg

Comment: [plot a secondary y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales) and don't use coord_flip, but switch the x and y aes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot with 2 y axes on each side and different scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales)

Comment: Hi tjebo, I wanted the secondary axis which is based on q_value. with some pathways, the q_values are the same (e.g. 0, 0, 0, 0), so do you think I should convert the q_value to factor/character then plot it again? but I try this morning, it wont work because we have only scale_y_continuous or scale_x_continuous? I will try to reverse the aes of x and y. appreciate if you could try my dataset and help to reproduce like the first image I have attached. I have read the link you attached, but seem not to work at all. I try again after work today. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you don't need a secondary axis per se to get the plot style you seek.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data, aes(x = NES, y = reorder(Pathway, NES), fill= Group)) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_col()  + 
  geom_text(aes(x = 2.5, y = reorder(Pathway, NES), label = q_value), hjust = 0) + 
  annotate("text", x = 2.5, y = length(data$Pathway) + 1, hjust = 0, fontface = "bold", label = "q_value" ) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(NA, 3),
                  ylim = c(NA, length(data$Pathway) + 1), 
                  clip = "off") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, size = 8),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12), 
        axis.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 8), 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  labs(x="Pathway", y="Normalized Enrichment Score",
       title="2Gy_5f vs. 0Gy")
```

[image]

And for future reference you can read in data in the format you pasted like so:

```r
data <- read_table( 
"
                                   Pathway    ES   NES p_value q_value  Group
                          HALLMARK_HYPOXIA  0.49  2.25   0.000   0.000    Top
HALLMARK_EPITHELIAL_MESENCHYMAL_TRANSITION  0.44  2.00   0.000   0.000    Top
                   HALLMARK_UV_RESPONSE_DN  0.45  1.98   0.000   0.000    Top
               HALLMARK_TGF_BETA_SIGNALING  0.48  1.77   0.003   0.004    Top
               HALLMARK_HEDGEHOG_SIGNALING  0.52  1.76   0.003   0.003    Top
          HALLMARK_ESTROGEN_RESPONSE_EARLY  0.38  1.73   0.000   0.004    Top
                HALLMARK_KRAS_SIGNALING_DN  0.37  1.69   0.000   0.005    Top
        HALLMARK_INTERFERON_ALPHA_RESPONSE  0.37  1.54   0.009   0.021    Top
          HALLMARK_TNFA_SIGNALING_VIA_NFKB  0.32  1.45   0.005   0.048    Top
                  HALLMARK_NOTCH_SIGNALING  0.42  1.42   0.070   0.059    Top
                      HALLMARK_COAGULATION  0.32  1.39   0.031   0.067    Top
                  HALLMARK_MITOTIC_SPINDLE  0.30  1.37   0.025   0.078    Top
                     HALLMARK_ANGIOGENESIS  0.40  1.37   0.088   0.074    Top
       HALLMARK_WNT_BETA_CATENIN_SIGNALING  0.35  1.23   0.173   0.216    Top
        HALLMARK_OXIDATIVE_PHOSPHORYLATION -0.65 -3.43   0.000   0.000 Bottom
                   HALLMARK_MYC_TARGETS_V1 -0.49 -2.56   0.000   0.000 Bottom
                      HALLMARK_E2F_TARGETS -0.45 -2.37   0.000   0.000 Bottom
                       HALLMARK_DNA_REPAIR -0.46 -2.33   0.000   0.000 Bottom
                     HALLMARK_ADIPOGENESIS -0.42 -2.26   0.000   0.000 Bottom
            HALLMARK_FATTY_ACID_METABOLISM -0.41 -2.06   0.000   0.000 Bottom
                       HALLMARK_PEROXISOME -0.43 -2.01   0.000   0.000 Bottom
                   HALLMARK_MYC_TARGETS_V2 -0.43 -1.84   0.003   0.001 Bottom
          HALLMARK_CHOLESTEROL_HOMEOSTASIS -0.42 -1.83   0.003   0.001 Bottom
              HALLMARK_ALLOGRAFT_REJECTION -0.34 -1.78   0.000   0.003 Bottom
                 HALLMARK_MTORC1_SIGNALING -0.32 -1.67   0.000   0.004 Bottom
                      HALLMARK_P53_PATHWAY -0.29 -1.52   0.000   0.015 Bottom
                   HALLMARK_UV_RESPONSE_UP -0.28 -1.41   0.013   0.036 Bottom
  HALLMARK_REACTIVE_OXYGEN_SPECIES_PATHWAY -0.35 -1.39   0.057   0.040 Bottom
                  HALLMARK_HEME_METABOLISM -0.26 -1.34   0.014   0.061 Bottom
                   HALLMARK_G2M_CHECKPOINT -0.23 -1.20   0.080   0.172 Bottom")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Dear Kene, Thank you so much for your invaluable input and your help is greatly appreciated. Big thank you.